# How to lock mouse movement using xdotool

Tags: scripts, xdotool

How can I achieve locking my mouse movement on the spot rather than moving to some defined X and Y coordinates? on the spot means if my mouse is in the middle, with just a keybind it'll lock it there rather than moving to the top right or left of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me the goal of such a script, but you could look up the current position, and keep setting the cursor position to that position.

You'll probably want a more reliable way of killing it, vs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  Think carefully about that before running the following:

```bash
eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
while true
do
  xdotool mousemove $X $Y
  sleep 0.1
done
```

---

`xdotool getmouselocation --shell` provides output like this:

```bash
$ xdotool getmouselocation --shell
X=420
Y=69
SCREEN=0
WINDOW=1
```

When you `eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)`, `$X` and `$Y` variables are set.

Comment: I am currently using xbindings and within that using xdotool, I'm thinking of assigning my button 9 (extra side mouse buttons) to lock the mouse movement and button 8 to disable it, any idea how to implement said changes...?

Comment: Create this as a script with executable flag (`chmod +x /usr/bin/mouselock`).  Execute that with a binding.  Then, execute `killall mouselock` or similar with another button.  I use `xdotool` to reset my SNES and live splits at the same time hehehe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try this out

Comment: Hello just tried this out, just wanted to know when I execute the script it locks it in place but it keeps flickering and returning back to the position where I left, is there any way to fix this up without my cursor flickering?

Comment: You could remove/decrease the timeout, which may reduce flickering, if you haven't already.  Otherwise, I'm not too sure.  Potentially, only move it if you detect a change in X or Y.  If you can't figure it out, feel free to ask and create a new question, vs comments.